# Connect to Oracle database Using ssis

Tags: oracle, ssis

I am all new with SSIS ( datatools 2010 ),I had installed oracle 11g enterprise edition , I want to use oracle as source ,i used OLE DB source "Microsoft OLE DB Provider For oracle" but when i test connection I get this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AYbC.png)

please can someone tell me what i should do .

Thank you in advance .

Comment: The page for this driver says _Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature. Instead, use Oracle's OLE DB provider._ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/appendixes/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-oracle?view=sql-server-ver15. Normally you need to specifically install the Oracle driver from Oracle before anything can connect to Oracle

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you have the correct version of drivers installed on a server where the SSIS package will be deployed to and executed (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/oracle-connector?view=sql-server-ver15#version-support) and that the bit-count is correct (not corresponding to the Windows one, but rather to the DataTools one). In case you have 32-bit and 64-bit drivers already installed, you would also need to make sure that the Data Source component in the package is picking the correct one (it will go for the first one listed in the environment variables).